# Cant design dialog in GUI Builder

Tags: codenameone

In netbeans when i create a new file and choose "other" and select GUI Builder Form and choose dialog from the combo box drop down menu. I can design the gui just fine. But nothing is added to the .java file! It works fine when designing a Form object, but not a Dialog object.

Has Codename one, not implemented this yet ?

Comment: Try building the project and then try opening the GUI builder again. I just tested this with 6.3 and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I just switched to native android under android studio. Condename one is just to buggy and janky